disable auth for OPTIONS method in apache
We have third party authentication and it was configured in apache.conf as below.
<Location /myapi>
  MyRequireAuth on
</Location>

means, when anyone send request to /myapi, it has to be validated by MyRequireAuth and it need X-Auth-Token in the request headers.
We are using axios for our js client and make requests to /myapi endpoints. We intercept the axios request and add X-Auth-Token in the headers.
import axios from "axios";

let axiosInstance = axios.create({ withCredentials: true });
  axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    if (config.method == "get") {
      return config;
    }
    let token = "";
    let name = "xauthtoken=";
    let ca = document.cookie.split(";");
    for (let i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
      let c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0) === " ") {
        c = c.substring(1);
      }
      if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) {
        token = c.substring(name.length, c.length);
      }
    }
    config.headers["X-Auth-Token"] = token;
    // config.headers["Access-Control-Allow-Origin"] = "https://local-example.com:4443";

    return config;
  });

It works fine when we deploy UI and API on same server.
During testing, we want to hit the /myapi from our UI which is running in localhost. Now request is not coming from same domain and it start giving CORS error for POST and PUT call.
When I debug the details in inspect mode in FireFox browse, I was able to see when there is POST call, axios send OPTIONS request first then POST. When axios send OPTIONS request its not sending X-Auth-Token.
What I want to do is, I want to tell apache, that if there is OPTIONS and HEAD method call, dont validate the auth. Make it disable for these 2 methods.
I tried
  <Location /myapi>
    <LimitExcept OPTIONS>
        MyRequireAuth on
    </LimitExcept>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://local-example.com:4443"
  </Location>

But this seems not working, it still try to validate OPTIONS method.
$ curl -I -X OPTIONS https://example.com/myapi/v1/fetch/
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Tue, 18 Jun 2024 21:15:08 GMT
P3P: policyref="https://policies.example.com/w3c/p3p.xml", CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADM DEV TAI PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi TELo OTPi OUR DELi SAMi OTRi UNRi PUBi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT STA POL HEA PRE LOC GOV"
Set-Cookie: token_it=4c57fbb3ccf9f40e; domain=.example.com; expires=Tue, 18 Jun 2024 21:45:08 GMT; path=/; secure; httponly
Set-Cookie: xauthtoken=d6607ccf794fefd1; domain=.example.com; expires=Tue, 18 Jun 2024 21:45:08 GMT; path=/; secure; httponly
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Location: https://example.com/oauth2/ausdqo06iBskQbfv0696/v1/authorize?response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20offline_access%20groups&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fapi%2Fcallback&client_id=0oa9umjnyyswQaZ6e1t7&state=eyJ0YXJnZXRfdXJsIjogImh0dHBzOi8vc3RnLXNhbmR5dWktMDEubmV0b3BzLmNvcnAuZ3ExLnlhaG9vLmNvbTo0NDMvb2t0YS9hcGkvdjEvY29sby9iZjEvY2x1c3Rlci9ncmMvZmV0Y2gvIiwgImNzcmZfdG9rZW4iOiAiZDY2MDdjY2Y3OTRmZWZkMSJ9&nonce=rBT-jhkrWdIFBGwjjxTUFKZsb4N_74lCcV8XosyHdQA&prompt=login
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 3181
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html

curl: (8) Weird server reply

I also added Access-Control-Allow-Origin to remove CORS error. But no luck :(
How to tell apache to not to give CORS even if request coming from different domain ?

what is the exact wording of the CORS error

What response status code is the OPTIONS request actually getting?

@JaromandaX I updated question with curl its returning 302.

@CBroe its returning 302, check curl command.

testing CORS with curl is pointless exercise

@JaromandaX I want to remove 302, then CORS will be gone.

then remove it - you control your server don't you?

@JaromandaX remove its means, I OPTIONS should return 200 because I want to disable the authentication for that.
